# Which is better using 1 admob publisher ID for all apps or multi ID's for each app?

Tags: android, admob

I'm and android developers , but I don't know how admob calculate revenue and clicks prices depending on impressions 
so is it better to use only 1 admob ID Publisher and use it for all apps so many impressions for this ID
or use for each app a different ID ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having different ids for each application is useful to see how each application is performing in regards to requests and eCPMs.  That allows one to better understand their market and adjust the apps as needed.